# How to use Storybook with a component using [routerLink] (Angular)?

Tags: javascript, angular, storybook, routerlink

I'm using Angular 11.0.5 and Storybook 6.1.14 and the following component:

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ui-navigation-item',
    template: `
        <a [ngClass]="{ 'no-decorations': !decorations }" [routerLink]="link">
            instead of ng-content
        </a>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./navigation-item.component.scss'],
})
export class NavigationItemComponent {
    @Input()
    link!: (string | null)[] | null;
    
    @Input()
    decorations:boolean = true;
    
    @HostBinding('class')
    @Input()
    variant: 'regular' | 'reduced' = 'regular';
}
```

Now when I try to add it to Storybook:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Meta } from '@storybook/angular';
import { NavigationItemComponent } from './navigation-item.component';

export default {
    title: 'Navigation Item',
    component: NavigationItemComponent,
    moduleMetadata: {
        imports: [RouterModule],
    },
} as Meta;

export const Primay = () => ({
    component: NavigationItemComponent,
    props: {
        link: ['/'],
    },
});
```

I'll get this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
        <a [ngClass]="{ 'no-decorations': !decorations }" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="link">
            instead of ng-content
        </a>
"): ng:///DynamicModule/NavigationItemComponent.html@1:52 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
        <a [ngClass]="{ 'no-decorations': !decorations }" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="link">
            instead of ng-content
        </a>
"): ng:///DynamicModule/NavigationItemComponent.html@1:52
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2444)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:12679)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:28429)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:28417)
    at compiler.js:28361
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:28361)
    at compiler.js:28274
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2434)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:28273) Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
        <a [ngClass]="{ 'no-decorations': !decorations }" [ERROR ->][routerLink]="link">
            instead of ng-content
        </a>
"): ng:///DynamicModule/NavigationItemComponent.html@1:52
    at syntaxError (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:8109:19)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:18344:19)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:34094:37)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:34082:69)
    at http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:34026:46
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:34026:19)
    at http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:33939:18
    at Object.then (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:8099:52)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:6006/vendors~main.f108962ff4c47d276288.bundle.js:33938:26)
```

How can I use [routerLink] within Storybook?

PS: Stackoverflow tells me to add some more details, but I don't know what else I should write. I searched and stumbled upon some issues, but they all don't solve the problem. I'm pretty sure I miss a small thing, but I couldn't figure out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the module imports within the [decorators](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/composite-component/) of the meta data:

```
import { Meta, moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';

export default {
    title: 'Navigation Item',
    component: NavigationItemComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            declarations: [NavigationItemComponent],
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
        }),
    ],
} as Meta;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing RouterModule in the story, import RouterTestingModule

Answer (score 0):

Importing RouterTestingModule used to work - before upgrading to Storybook v7. Since upgrading this doesn't seem to be enough.

My setup is like this:

```
export default {
  title: 'Component Title',
  component: MyComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [MyModule, RouterTestingModule],
    }),
  ],
};
```

when I start up Storybook this gives the following error:
[storybook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVtEi.png)